# ssh connection from Mac OS Sierra 10.12 to AWS Linux Server broken

Tags: ssh, sshd

I am trying to retain ssh connection from mac OS Sierra to Linux box. But after few mins of inactivity, it shows

```
$ packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.227.255.110 port 22: Broken pipe.
```

How to resolve the problem.

In `etc/ssh/ssh_config` file, I have uncommented the line

```
#   SendEnv # (no default)
#   ServerAliveCountMax 3
    ServerAliveInterval 10
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   TCPKeepAlive yes
#   Tunnel no
```

Comment: Did you make the above changes on the client or the server? If you want the server to send a no alive packet to keep the connection open then you need to set `ClientAliveInterval` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server side to a value of `60` which will send the packet every 60 seconds.

Comment: I did that in my client side..as in server i dont have access